# Verifying Installation Directory is FAT

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, installation

I'd like to know how I can set up a way to verify that the installation directory is FAT/FAT32/exFAT/any USB without USN Journal.

I assume it's something here: [image]

I couldn't find any documentation on what I'm trying to do. I'd try to add some support in my program directly, but by doing the check, it may cause issues.

Comment: Did the battle with the file system go well? NTFS seems to be the file system where everything is possible and nothing is (all that) easy.

Answer (score 0):

***First things first***: Visual Studio Setup Projects are quite limited, you might be better off looking for a more capable deployment tool / framework: **[Application setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617506/application-setup/51618424#51618424)**.

---

***NTFS Only***: That sounds pretty exotic. It isn't even possible to install Windows on anything but NTFS nowadays? [**From superuser.com**](https://superuser.com/questions/775960/does-windows-8-have-to-be-installed-on-ntfs): "***Windows Vista and higher*** will not install on a FAT32 partition and can only be installed on an NTFS partition. This is probably due to the use of symlinks (which are not supported in FAT32)." I don't have an MSDN link for you to verify, but I am pretty sure the above is correct.

---

***Built-In MSI Feature***: It is possible that there is a built in property in MSI that will be set to the system drive's file system. I am not familiar with any such properties.

***Custom Action***: If you are on **Windows XP**, I suppose you need a custom action and then a call to either **WMI** or directly via the **Win32 AP**I to determine what the file system really is.

***Win32***: An answer with some sample mock-up code for a Win32 check of file system:
**[Determine what filesystem a partition is of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380454/determine-what-filesystem-a-partition-is-of/380508#380508)**. An inline version tested with VS2017, C++ console project:

```c++
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN // Exclude rarely used stuff from Windows.h (Crypto stuff?)

int main()
{
    WCHAR FSType[512];

    if (GetVolumeInformationW(L"C:\\", NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, FSType, ARRAYSIZE(FSType))) {
        MessageBox(NULL, FSType, L"File System:", MB_OK); 
        // TEXT("File System:") instead of L"File System:" if need be?
    }
}
```

***WMI***: You should be able to get the information from `Win32_LogicalDisk`:

```sql
SELECT FileSystem FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID='C:'
```

***FileSystemObject***: I forgot that the COM scripting runtime can be used:

```vb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set drive = fso.GetDrive(fso.GetDriveName("C:"))
MsgBox drive.FileSystem
```

Comment: I'm trying to prevent the installation from proceeding if the selected drive is NTFS. I don't support WinXP.

Comment: @Cryptoman: You've got it backward. Not proceeding on NTFS will prevent you from using anything *except* Windows XP, because Vista and on **only use** NTFS.

Comment: Seeing as NTFS is required for the system drive from Vista onwards, do you then install to a secondary partition? Or do you install to a USB drive? In the latter case I would think you don't really need an installer? Maybe just a zip? Or a custom EXE that writes the USB key specifically.

Comment: @KenWhite I understand now. Either way, don't worry: my program will work on anything with USN Journal disabled.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Just install on a USB. We do need an installer.

Comment: [**I would check the links this guy provides**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27593415/129130). Maybe search [**github.com**](http://www.github.com) for an example using these calls.